# Strategy for keeping separate Databases in Sync

Tags: sql, caching, nosql, synchronization

I have a NoSQL database that we are using for data processing, as it can be used for my application faster than SQL can. I'm treating our NoSQL database almost like a cache of information, with the SQL being the authority of data, and the NoSQL store being updated with changes. Right now this is being done through our application, so when a request comes in for a change, it is made in the SQL database, and the NoSQL database. This is failing at times as sometimes the NoSQL update fails, or other situations cause the NoSQL database to get out of sync.

I could do a batch update every X minutes, however it is a lot of information in the data stores, and it would take hours to ensure that they are in sync. We have some timestamps to do a difference of what has been changed, but this is not always accurate.

I'm wondering what some recommended strategy for keeping a data store(secondary database cache) in sync with my main store are?

Answer (score 5):

I know I've done with this with messaging in the past - specifically JMS with ActiveMQ. I would send the updates to a NoSQL store (Mongo) by using a queue. This way messages could accumulate in the queue and if the connection to the NoSQL store ever got severed, it could pick up where it left off.

It worked really well because ActiveMQ was really stable and simple to work with.

I've always seen this done with diffs like you mentioned. You introduce date fields all over and then keep track of the latest sync. The nice thing about this approach is that it easily allows you to replay transactions by modifying the last sync date.

One last piece of advice ... write good tools around pumping data from point A to point B (in this case SQL to NoSQL). I wrote several tools to bulk load the NoSQL store from SQL at my last job and it made life easy if anything got *really* out of sync. Between scripts and bulk loading processes, I could always recover.

Comment: You mentioned date fields, did you do this at the message and NoSQL entity level? Did you do a stateful update(append) or a stateless update(entire state in JMS message)? For your date fields, did just ignore any of the "older" JMS messages if your NoSQL entity was newer? I'm using Web Services for my CRUD, did you have similar concept in the queue's for doing CRUD?

Comment: We put date fields at the record level in SQL. CreateDate, UpdateDate. Then you can run your diffs against those and ship what has changed/what is new. At the application level we'd write an object to SQL and then serialize it as JSON and send it via JMS. For all writes to NoSQL we did upserts. This avoided the issue of having to know what was newer. Example: Someone writes a new article in the CMS. We write it to SQL and also send a JMS message with the object serialized as JSON. The NoSQL write would upsert (write new if not there, update if exists). Does that help?

Comment: If someone deleted an article, was that delete a separate queue, or did you use one queue and it had a field for operation(ADD, DELETE) or did you have one queue for adds, one for deletes?

Comment: Real confession time: I left the job before we implemented delete. Ha. It was a really rare case, but yeah I would have implemented a separate queue to handle deletes. I liked to keep the queues separate and distinct. It became hard to try and use one queue for multiple purposes.

Comment: I agree with that, but my concern was if you get someone to do an add, then a delete of the same element, how do you address the potential that the queue's could get read out of order?

Comment: That's a good point. Better to put them in one queue so they get operated on in order. Otherwise you're right you'd have to reconcile the operations.

Comment: To my system, our ADD and DELETE operation take the same object, so it's not a matter of us converting the objects. Thanks for all your advice.